# Matlab: fprintf error

Tags: matlab, printf, editor

I need to save some data in a .txt file, which works great except for this one line.

```
%Writing the rest of the Data to the file
fprintf(fid, '%u',speedNum);
fprintf(fid, ' ');
fprintf(fid,speedUnit); %That would be the line
```

in speedUnit are different values (none work) one of which is: 'Frames per Min '

The error I get is:

> Error using fprintf Invalid format.
>
> Error in RackWriter>tag_OnOff_Callback (line 414)
>   fprintf(fid,speedUnit);
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in RackWriter (line 42)
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in
>   @(hObject,eventdata)RackWriter('tag_OnOff_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

Can somebody help me??? Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(fid, ' ');
fprintf(fid,speedUnit);
```

are both function calls with only two input arguments. In the [documentation of `fprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) you'll find this:

`fprintf(formatSpec, A1)` formats data and displays the results on the screen.

So in your function calls `fprintf` tries to use `fid` as format specification. This is not possible, therefore you get an error.

```
fprintf(fid, '%s', ' ');
fprintf(fid, '%s', speedUnit);
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. 1. I got lines that work fine without %s and they work fine and 2. it still doesnt work. now i get: Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Comment: if `speedUnit` only contains one element try the comma separated output syntax `speedUnit{:}`, if it contains more elements use the cell index instead of `:`